# Cannot add a google account to android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am having a **problem connecting my android emulator to gmail**. I cannot add my gmail account even though I can browse the web.

I go to the `Accounts and Sync/add account/google/sign in`, and put in my gmail address and password and then get the following message after a long wait -
**"Can't establish a reliable data connection to the server"**

I am going through a *company proxy* so I suspect this may be the problem. This also happens if I try the create new option.

Does anybody know what port needs to be open for this activity to occur, if indeed this is the problem?
Or if anybody has any alternative explanations I would be keen to hear them, as I am stumped.

I am running Android 2.2 with the google apis.

Comment: OK I have found the answer and it is on this forum at the address below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954000/can-not-add-google-account-in-google-app-emulator

Answer (score 2):

THE FOLLOWING SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE SINCE API 16 OR 17 (not sure of the number)

- Click Add Account, EMail.
- Enter your gmail address and password
- Click on Manual Setup
- Choose Exchange
- For the Domain\Username enter \yourEmail@gmail.com (don't forget the backslash at start, and the @gmail.com at the end)
- Server: m.google.com (not gmail.com)
- Check use SSL (should be already checked)
- Click Next, next, next

That's it !