# How to Sync a Google Email Account on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to sync google mail account in Emulator, but after filling account details i am getting below screen and whenever i do click on **Sync Now** not Syncing my account...

**Screen 1:**

[image]

**Screen 2:**

[image]

as you can see Sync Now option, but whenever i do click on this menu, not Syncing my account

before asking here i searched a lot, but did not get anything helpful..

Comment: Can you upload the code you tried, with error log ?

Comment: Have you tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336693/cannot-add-a-google-account-to-android-emulator

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't sync any Google Services Account on the emulator. The emulator doesn't include any google services such as Play Store and Google Sign in among other which are required for account syncing.

To test syncing you would need to use a physical device instead of an emulator

Comment: but 7 months ago i have created and synced an account on Emulator and was able to use that to send emails, so what's the reason now

Comment: There is some hack you can do, I can't remember the steps to make the emulator, work but that involves manually downloading and installing each required APK. Other than that I don't see how you could have synced Gmail on the emulator, as this has never been available as the emulator has never had any Google Services installed

Answer (score 0):

You can use genymotion emulator.

You can use the Google Play Services APK from
https://www.mediafire.com/?qbbt4lhyu9q10ix

Drag and drop it in the emulator (for version 4.4.4)

You should now have the Google Play store too.